# How do your Adventurers League characters use their downtime days?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, downtime

With the rather rigid (but welcome) parameters set for the Adventurers League, I was wondering how your AL-compliant characters use their downtime days? I assume that many of use use them to level up, but I was hoping for a list of best-practices, or just bright ideas, for how else you use them!

Comment: @nitsua60: if you don't want to see a list, how will your proposed question format change the outcome?

Comment: ok then, I will submit to your greater experience. Should I "vote to delete"? What's the best way to remove the question?

Comment: Back to the original question: Encounters or Expeditions?

Comment: Honestly I'd like to see answers to this as well.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie actually, while I think the question is not well-worded, I think it's got an objectively correct and final answer: see [pages 5-6](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/ALPGv3_print.pdf) of the ALPG. What do you think?

Comment: @nitsua60 Yes, I had a look at the ALPG for both Season 2 and 3. If no other activities are permitted, than I guess the question is moot.

Comment: @nitsua60 Yeah it might get *one* objective answer, but as currently written it's a survey and *other* well-meaning citizens will answer the question as-written if it seems to have the "not closed" stamp of approval. It needs to be rewritten to not be a survey before it can stay open.

Comment: @Maadiah if the question were "what can I do with DT in AL" and the answer were the enumerated list from the ALPG, along with the AL-specific proscription that these--and module-specific one-offs (which I don't recall seeing, but I've only run about half of each of seasons 2 & 3)--are the *only allowable* activities... would *your* question be answered?

Comment: @nitsua60: In my opinion, it would be a misuse of yours and other people's time to just refer to the ALPGs. (unless someone doesnt know they exist and have a section on the topic). If this forum only allows binary-type answers, and isn't intended to contribute RAI advice or proactively move the community forwards by proposing, crafting and refining best-practices, then I withdraw the question. I would, however, like to thank all of you for your contributions :)

Comment: It's not that this site (not forum) only allows binary answers. This question is asking for people to just brainstorm a list of ideas, with [no obvious way for voters to tell which answers are better than others](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). This Stack is the place for when you want to find the *right* or *best* answer to a question. For a survey that has many right answers, the correct tool is a [discussion forum](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5449).